# angularjs with soundmanager, update DOM on whileloading

Tags: angularjs, soundmanager2

I'm new to Angularjs, and I'm trying to create a simple player using soundManager library.

The problem i'm facing is about updating the DOM, during sound loading/playing.

The soundManager `Sound` object exposes some dynamic properties like `bytesLoaded` or `position` and I'm trying to figure out how to bind them to the DOM.

I tried with something like

```
<span ng-bind="sound.bytesLoaded"></span>
```

where `sound` is an instance of the sound object attached to the root `$scope`, but it seems the DOM is updated only once in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that the `sound.bytesLoaded` is updated in non-angular world like, callback function of bytes loaded or some similar callback methods which is non-angular world.

To make the view update while updating the model value in non-angular world, you may need to call the `$scope.$apply` method from within the callback method of the SM2.

Some pseudo code:

```javascript
sound.on('bytesLoaded', function(bytesLoaded){
  // Imagine you have some similar kind of the callback in SM2,
  // where you will be updating the sound.bytestLoaded property.
  sound.bytesLoaded = bytesLoaded;
  $scope.$apply(); // please make sure you call have this line
                   // where you are updating the bytesLoaded property. 

})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems to make sense to me, even if I'm not very confident with the `$apply` method. I feel like the Angularjs doc is a little bit hard to explore.

Comment: It could be helpful for others: http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq (Section: $watch & $apply)